# AzSK scan asking for user choice in pipeline

Tags: security, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-pipelines, devsecops

I am facing below issue in AzSK_SVTs release pipeline:

```
Framework\Abstracts\CommandBase.ps1:250 char:22
$userChoice = Read-Host "Continue (Y/N)"
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Read-Host], PSInvalidOper
ationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.R
eadHostCommand
```

Its asking for user choice in pipeline, how can we resolve it?

Comment: It seems this issue comes from your `CommandBase.ps1` file, have you try to execute this powershell scripts directly without azure devops pipeline to check if this issue is related to the azure devops?

Comment: I tried running the scan locally and it worked fine, it asked me for choice and once the input was provided it continued the scan. But in the pipeline we are using service connection, and the assumption was it wont ask for user choice there but its asking and as of now I do not know any way to provide the input. If the choice needs to be provided for the first time then that is a manual thing which is not good for automation.

Comment: which task you are using to execute the `.ps1` scripts? Azure powershell task?

Comment: I have added only one task in pipeline i.e. AzSK Security Verification Tests
and all possible configurations are provided. I am not running any ps file separately.  I thought the user choice is asked only if we run the scan manually in powershell but that is not the case.

Comment: I went through CommandBase.ps1 file, and the issue seems to be because of other running powershell instances. Looking for to fix it now.

Comment: How about the result? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Yes, we prepared new agent from scratch and used it, everything worked fine on that.